# Is there a way of using WMI to detect if a user changes a files permissions or shares the file?

Tags: c#, wmi

I am in the process of creating an application that will allow a user to be informed (in real time) when a client changes the permission of a file or shares the file on a network.

This is possible by building an initial index of all **shared** files/folders on startup (the application will be set to run on startup) and then checking this list at a set interval, however, I will then have a gap between when the client performs the action and when it is detected.

I would also like to remove this overhead by using WMI.

Any ideas?

Comment: As your question stands, its a little too broad for this site. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you have a more specific problem, you can show us your relevant code, explain what behavior you are seeing, and explain how this is different from what you expect.

Comment: Ok, would it be better stated as: "Is there any way to detect when a file is shared using wmi?"

Comment: Changing the question title is not a substantial change. If you read the link from my first comment, the two things this question lacks is the "Minimal" (code showing us what you have attempted) and "Verifiable" (something that others could see if they tried what you tried, as well as a way to give a definitive answer to your question). Right now your post doesn't have a **specific** issue. It is a very general problem that you are trying to solve. If you don't know where to start, this would indicate that you need to do more research before asking a question on this site.